Programmatically Accessing and Parsing Google Watchlist Data
I'm developing a mobile app that requires real-time access to a user's Google Watchlist. The goal is to retrieve information about items added to the watchlist, items already watched, and their associated streaming partners with direct links.
Key Requirements:

Real-time data: The solution should provide up-to-date information about watchlist changes.
Data structure: The returned data should clearly distinguish between added and watched items.
Streaming partner information: For each item, the response should include details about the streaming partner(s) and direct links to watch the content.
Avoid web scraping: Due to potential performance and reliability issues, web scraping is not a viable option for a mobile app.

Questions:

Is there an official Google API or SDK that provides access to user watchlist data?
If no API exists, are there any alternative approaches or workarounds to achieve the desired functionality?
What data structure would be suitable for representing the watchlist data, including added and watched items with streaming partner details?
How can real-time updates be efficiently implemented to reflect changes in the user's watchlist?

I'm open to suggestions and alternative approaches that meet the specified requirements without relying on web scraping.
Additional Considerations:

User authentication and authorization mechanisms for accessing watchlist data.
Potential challenges and limitations of different approaches.
Performance implications of real-time updates and data synchronization.

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
